# Already checked checkboxes want to uncheck and unchecked check boxes want to check using master check box in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a master check box, and also have a set of check boxes under it, some of them already checked and some of them unchecked. My query is If I will check the master check box then already checked check boxes want to uncheck and unchecked check boxes want to check.

eg:
[image]

Comment: You need to share your html and what you have already tried

Comment: have you tried anything from your side?

Comment: Is this a `check` tongue-twister?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `prop()` method

```js
$('#master').on('click', function() {  
    $('.branch').each(function(){
        $(this).prop('checked',!$(this).prop('checked'))
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="master">master</br>
<input type="checkbox" class="branch">1
<input type="checkbox" class="branch">2
<input type="checkbox" class="branch" checked>3
<input type="checkbox" class="branch">4
<input type="checkbox" class="branch">5
<input type="checkbox" class="branch" checked>6
<input type="checkbox" class="branch">7
<input type="checkbox" class="branch">8
<input type="checkbox" class="branch" checked>9
```

Comment: This is what the answer and I have cliked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per your query

> If I will check the master check box then already checked check boxes want to uncheck and unchecked check boxes want to check

Just try, it will work

```js
  $('#master').on('click', function() {
 if($(this).is(':checked')){
      $('.branch').trigger('click');
    }             
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="master">master</br>
<input type="checkbox" class="branch">1
<input type="checkbox" class="branch">2
<input type="checkbox" class="branch" checked>3
<input type="checkbox" class="branch">4
<input type="checkbox" class="branch">5
<input type="checkbox" class="branch" checked>6
<input type="checkbox" class="branch">7
<input type="checkbox" class="branch">8
<input type="checkbox" class="branch" checked>9
```

Answer (score 0):

Without triggering all inputs, try this:

```js
var masterCheckbox = jQuery("#master");
            
masterCheckbox.on("change", function()
{
  if(masterCheckbox.is(":checked"))
  {
    var checkboxes = jQuery(".myCheckbox");

    //get all checked and unchecked
    var checked = checkboxes.filter(":checked");
    var notchecked = checkboxes.filter(":not(:checked)");

    checked.prop( "checked", false );

    notchecked.prop( "checked", true );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="master" />
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" checked />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" checked />
<input type="checkbox"  class="myCheckbox" />
```